# how to quickly insert data as select

Tags: oracle, performance, insert, query-performance

In an Oracle DB have about 200M rows (about 20GB data) that I would like to insert into another table by

```
insert into foo select * from bar where some_unimportant=condition;
```

How do I do that the fastest way if I can always drop the foo table and redo the insert in case of any problem? Like, I don't need to be able to do a rollback.
Since I can drop the foo table, I have complete control over its creation also, if there are some good options to use to speed up the insert.

Of course, after the inserts, I wish the table to behave as an ordinary table (support undo by using rollback, etc.)

**UPDATE**: The table was created as an IOT, so I guess that changes things. Should I run

```
 alter index foo_pk nologging;
```

also?

Comment: Ok, IOT is a special kind of animal with a lot of limitations. For example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm In 11.2, `Direct-path INSERT is not supported for an index-organized table (IOT) if it is not partitioned, if it has a mapping table, or if it is reference by a materialized view.`. So we need the details of your table and at least the version of the database. The restriction for non-partitioned IOT exists even in 19c.

Comment: @BalazsPapp its an old one, 10.2. So not much luck then with IOT I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Improving INSERT Performance with Direct-Path INSERT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-134D6EB6-219E-4820-AB54-8C60067A8F0F)

Example:

```
alter table foo nologging;
alter session force parallel query parallel 8;
alter session force parallel dml parallel 8;
insert /*+ append */ into foo select * from bar where some_unimportant=condition;
```

Comment: I tried this, but the datafile called undotbs01.dbf (I guess that is undo tablespace) grows a lot. Something else I must do or missed?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you dont care about FOO'and can freely drop it, just drop it and make a CTAS using parallel, it will be the fastest. Use the alter sessions sugested by Balazs Papp, maybe add a third one (force parallel DDL).